# How to fetch Riak object, change its value and store it back with all indexes in Python

Tags: python, database, riak

I am using Riak database to store my Python application objects that are used and processed in parallel by multiple scripts. Because of that, I need to lock them in various places, to avoid being processed by more than one script at once, like that:

```
riak_bucket = riak_connect('clusters')
cluster = riak_bucket.get(job_uuid).get_data()
cluster['status'] = 'locked'
riak_obj = riak_bucket.new(job_uuid, data=cluster)
riak_obj.add_index('username_bin', cluster['username'])
riak_obj.add_index('hostname_bin', cluster['hostname'])
riak_obj.store()
```

The thing is, this is quite a bit of code to do one simple, repeatable thing, and given the fact locking occurs quite often, I would like to find a simpler, cleaner way of doing that. I've tried to write a function to do locking/unlocking, like that (for a different object, called 'build'):

```
def build_job_locker(uuid, status='locked'):
    riak_bucket = riak_connect('builds')
    build = riak_bucket.get(uuid).get_data()
    build['status'] = status
    riak_obj = riak_bucket.new(build['uuid'], data=build)
    riak_obj.add_index('cluster_uuid_bin', build['cluster_uuid'])
    riak_obj.add_index('username_bin', build['username'])
    riak_obj.store()
    # when locking, return the locked db object to avoid fetching it again
    if 'locked' in status:
        return build
    else:
        return
```

but since the objects are obviously quite different one from another, they've different indexes and so on, I ended up writing a locking function per every object... which is almost as much messy as not having the functions at all and repeating the code.

The question is: is there a way to write a general function to do so, knowing that every object has a 'status' field, that'd lock them in db retaining all indexes and other attributes? Or, perhaps, there is another, easier way I havent thought about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, and questions asked on various IRC channels it seems that this is not doable, as there's no way to fetch this kind of metadata about objects from Riak.